# How to roll up multiple rows into one if they meet a condition involving all the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with names and visits data as follows

| Name | Visitlicensedate | LicenseExpiredate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1/1/2020 | 3/30/2020 |
| John | 2/1/2020 | 5/2/2020 |
| John | 6/1/2020 | 9/30/2020 |
| James | 3/15/2020 | 6/14/2020 |

For each name on here, I want the results to roll up visitlicensedates into one (the first) if the visits are within 60 days of each other and use the last Expired date as the new licenseexpiredate. If the visit license was issued more than 60 days after the last, I want that to begin a new record so the results will be as follows:

| Name | Visitlicensedate | LicenseExpiredate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1/1/2020 | 5/2/2020 |
| John | 6/1/2020 | 9/30/2020 |
| James | 3/15/2020 | 6/14/2020 |

I couldn't figure out the solution for this.

Comment: If you have absolutely no idea where to start, then I recommend taking some SQL tutorials elsewhere. Otherwise someone here might write your query for you, but then they are doing all the work and you're not learning the basics.

Comment: I do have the basics. I tried to use the max function but obviously that wouldn't work because it would roll up every record, ignoring the condition

Comment: Looks like a kind of gaps and islands problem. A lot of answers could be found here.

Comment: This is a gaps and island issue; you first need to put your data into groups so that you can then use `MAX`. You'll need to use `LAG` first to check if the prior row was within 60 days, and then probably a windowed `COUNT` to get the data into groups. Then finally you can use `MAX` on those groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use the gaps and islands approach to put the data into groups and perform the calculation per group.

```
WITH table1 AS (
SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Visitlicensedate) AS rownum,
   LAG(Visitlicensedate) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Visitlicensedate) AS nextvisit,
   MIN(Visitlicensedate) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) AS sortdate
FROM mytable
),
table2 AS (
SELECT *,
   DATEDIFF(day, nextvisit, Visitlicensedate) AS gap
FROM table1
),
table3 AS (
SELECT *,
   SUM(CASE WHEN gap < 60 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY rownum) AS grp
FROM table2
),
table4 AS (
SELECT Name, MIN(sortdate) AS sortdate, MIN(Visitlicensedate) AS Visitlicense_Date,
   MAX(LicenseExpiredate) AS LicenseExpire_Date
FROM table3
GROUP BY Name, grp
)
SELECT Name, Visitlicense_Date, LicenseExpire_Date
FROM table4
ORDER BY sortdate;
```

See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=42153daf29fbfb67e548ee1e2af7e1c7)

**Result**

| Name | Visitlicense_Date | LicenseExpire_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2020-01-01 | 2020-05-02 |
| John | 2020-06-01 | 2020-09-30 |
| James | 2020-03-15 | 2020-06-14 |

Comment: The real deal. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome @smoove

Answer (score 0):

You can use this stored procedure to get your expected results:

```
create procedure my_custom_sp
as

create table #tbl (
    [name] varchar(20),
    [visitlicensedate] date,
    [licenseExpiredate] date
)

declare cur cursor for 

select [name], [visitlicensedate] from tbl

declare @name varchar(20), @visitlicensedate date

open cur
fetch next from cur into @name, @visitlicensedate

while @@FETCH_STATUS =0 
begin   
    
    insert into #tbl ([name], [visitlicensedate], [licenseExpiredate])
    select [name], min([visitlicensedate]), max([licenseExpiredate])    
    from tbl t1 where [name] = @name 
    and [visitlicensedate] < DATEADD(d,60,@visitlicensedate)
    and not exists (
        select * from #tbl t2 where [name] = @name 
        and DATEDIFF(d,t2.[visitlicensedate],t1.[visitlicensedate]) < 60 
    )
    group by [name]
            
    fetch next from cur into @name, @visitlicensedate
end
close cur
deallocate cur

select * from #tbl

go
```

Result

```
exec my_custom_sp

/*
name    visitlicensedate    licenseExpiredate
John    2020-01-01          2020-05-02
John    2020-06-01          2020-09-30
James   2020-03-15          2020-06-14
*/
```